# Artifactory Bower resolver returns 404 on some repos

Tags: proxy, bower, artifactory

We have to use artifactory to proxy npm and bower packages.
npm works fine and bower seems to work either, only on some repos it returns a 404 error:

```
[INFO] Running 'bower install -V --allow-root --config.strict-ssl false' in /apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/de.hygieia/UI
[INFO] bower modernizr#~2.8.3      not-cached art://Modernizr/Modernizr#~2.8.3
[INFO] bower modernizr#~2.8.3         resolve art://Modernizr/Modernizr#~2.8.3
[INFO] bower angular-animate#~1.5.9       not-cached art://angular/bower-angular-animate#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-animate#~1.5.9          resolve art://angular/bower-angular-animate#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-sanitize#~1.5.9      not-cached art://angular/bower-angular-sanitize#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-sanitize#~1.5.9         resolve art://angular/bower-angular-sanitize#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-cookies#~1.5.9       not-cached art://angular/bower-angular-cookies#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-cookies#~1.5.9          resolve art://angular/bower-angular-cookies#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular#~1.5.9               not-cached art://angular/bower-angular#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular#~1.5.9                  resolve art://angular/bower-angular#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-ui-router#~0.4.2     not-cached art://angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower#~0.4.2
[INFO] bower angular-ui-router#~0.4.2        resolve art://angular-ui/angular-ui-router-bower#~0.4.2
[INFO] bower angular-bootstrap#~2.3.0     not-cached art://angular-ui/bootstrap-bower#~2.3.0
[INFO] bower angular-bootstrap#~2.3.0        resolve art://angular-ui/bootstrap-bower#~2.3.0
[INFO] bower bootstrap-sweetalert#~0.4.5  not-cached art://lipis/bootstrap-sweetalert#~0.4.5
[INFO] bower bootstrap-sweetalert#~0.4.5     resolve art://lipis/bootstrap-sweetalert#~0.4.5
[INFO] bower operative#~0.4.4             not-cached art://padolsey/operative#~0.4.4
[INFO] bower operative#~0.4.4                resolve art://padolsey/operative#~0.4.4
[INFO] bower angular-chartist.js#~3.3.13  not-cached art://paradox41/angular-chartist.js#~3.3.13
[INFO] bower angular-chartist.js#~3.3.13     resolve art://paradox41/angular-chartist.js#~3.3.13
[INFO] bower angular-validation-match#~1.5.0       not-cached art://TheSharpieOne/angular-validation-match#~1.5.0
[INFO] bower angular-validation-match#~1.5.0          resolve art://TheSharpieOne/angular-validation-match#~1.5.0
[INFO] bower chartist#~0.9.5                       not-cached art://gionkunz/chartist-js#~0.9.5
[INFO] bower chartist#~0.9.5                          resolve art://gionkunz/chartist-js#~0.9.5
[INFO] bower moment#~2.9.0                         not-cached art://moment/moment#~2.9.0
[INFO] bower moment#~2.9.0                            resolve art://moment/moment#~2.9.0
[INFO] bower lodash#~2.4.1                         not-cached art://lodash/lodash#~2.4.1
[INFO] bower lodash#~2.4.1                            resolve art://lodash/lodash#~2.4.1
[INFO] bower components-font-awesome#~4.2.0        not-cached art://components/font-awesome#~4.2.0
[INFO] bower components-font-awesome#~4.2.0           resolve art://components/font-awesome#~4.2.0
[INFO] bower bootstrap#~3.3.2                      not-cached art://twbs/bootstrap#~3.3.2
[INFO] bower bootstrap#~3.3.2                         resolve art://twbs/bootstrap#~3.3.2
[INFO] bower hygieia-jstz-detect#~1.0.5            not-cached art://amitmawkin/bower-jstz#~1.0.5
[INFO] bower hygieia-jstz-detect#~1.0.5               resolve art://amitmawkin/bower-jstz#~1.0.5
[INFO] bower dexie#~1.2.0                          not-cached art://dfahlander/dexie.js#~1.2.0
[INFO] bower dexie#~1.2.0                             resolve art://dfahlander/dexie.js#~1.2.0
[INFO] bower ng-sortable#~1.3.2                    not-cached art://a5hik/ng-sortable#~1.3.2
[INFO] bower ng-sortable#~1.3.2                       resolve art://a5hik/ng-sortable#~1.3.2
[INFO] bower regression-js#~1.3.0                  not-cached art://Tom-Alexander/regression-js#~1.3.0
[INFO] bower regression-js#~1.3.0                     resolve art://Tom-Alexander/regression-js#~1.3.0
[INFO] bower angular-ui-select#^0.18.0             not-cached art://angular-ui/ui-select#^0.18.0
[INFO] bower angular-ui-select#^0.18.0                resolve art://angular-ui/ui-select#^0.18.0
[INFO] bower angular-chart.js#^1.1.1               not-cached art://jtblin/angular-chart.js#^1.1.1
[INFO] bower angular-chart.js#^1.1.1                  resolve art://jtblin/angular-chart.js#^1.1.1
[INFO] bower json-logic-js#^1.0.11                 not-cached art://jwadhams/json-logic-js#^1.0.11
[INFO] bower json-logic-js#^1.0.11                    resolve art://jwadhams/json-logic-js#^1.0.11
[INFO] bower angular-jwt#~0.1.8                    not-cached art://auth0/angular-jwt#~0.1.8
[INFO] bower angular-jwt#~0.1.8                       resolve art://auth0/angular-jwt#~0.1.8
[INFO] bower gridstack#~0.2.6                      not-cached art://troolee/gridstack.js#~0.2.6
[INFO] bower gridstack#~0.2.6                         resolve art://troolee/gridstack.js#~0.2.6
[INFO] bower gridstack-angular#^0.5.0              not-cached art://kdietrich/gridstack-angular#^0.5.0
[INFO] bower gridstack-angular#^0.5.0                 resolve art://kdietrich/gridstack-angular#^0.5.0
[INFO] bower angular-utils-pagination#~0.11.1      not-cached art://michaelbromley/angularUtils-pagination#~0.11.1
[INFO] bower angular-utils-pagination#~0.11.1         resolve art://michaelbromley/angularUtils-pagination#~0.11.1
[INFO] bower angular-rateit#~3.0.2                 not-cached art://akempes/angular-rateit#~3.0.2
[INFO] bower angular-rateit#~3.0.2                    resolve art://akempes/angular-rateit#~3.0.2
[INFO] bower angular-mocks#~1.5.9                  not-cached art://angular/bower-angular-mocks#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower angular-mocks#~1.5.9                     resolve art://angular/bower-angular-mocks#~1.5.9
[INFO] bower karma-jasmine#0.3.8                   not-cached art://karma-runner/karma-jasmine#0.3.8
[INFO] bower karma-jasmine#0.3.8                      resolve art://karma-runner/karma-jasmine#0.3.8
[INFO] bower sinonjs#^1.17.1                       not-cached art://blittle/sinon.js#^1.17.1
[INFO] bower sinonjs#^1.17.1                          resolve art://blittle/sinon.js#^1.17.1
[INFO] bower jasmine-sinon#^0.4.0                  not-cached art://froots/jasmine-sinon#^0.4.0
[INFO] bower jasmine-sinon#^0.4.0                     resolve art://froots/jasmine-sinon#^0.4.0
[ERROR] bower modernizr#~2.8.3                        EREQUEST Request to http://artifactory.ads.vhv.de/artifactory/api/bower/bower-remote-github/refs/Modernizr/Modernizr returned 404 status code.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Additional error details:
[ERROR] [object Object]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Stack trace:
[ERROR] Error: Request to http://artifactory.ads.vhv.de/artifactory/api/bower/bower-remote-github/refs/Modernizr/Modernizr returned 404 status code.
[ERROR]     at createError (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower-art-resolver/lib/createError.js:4:15)
[ERROR]     at Request._callback (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower-art-resolver/lib/request.js:27:33)
[ERROR]     at Request.self.callback (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower-art-resolver/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
[ERROR]     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
[ERROR]     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
[ERROR]     at Request.<anonymous> (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower-art-resolver/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
[ERROR]     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
[ERROR]     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
[ERROR]     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower-art-resolver/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
[ERROR]     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
[ERROR] From previous event:
[ERROR]     at PackageRepository.fetch (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/PackageRepository.js:46:14)
[ERROR]     at Manager._fetch (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:382:10)
[ERROR]     at Array.forEach (native)
[ERROR]     at Manager.resolve (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:127:23)
[ERROR]     at Project._bootstrap (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:672:10)
[ERROR]     at /apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:83:25
[ERROR] From previous event:
[ERROR]     at Manager.resolve (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Manager.js:119:24)
[ERROR]     at Project._bootstrap (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:672:10)
[ERROR]     at /apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:83:25
[ERROR] From previous event:
[ERROR]     at Project.install (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/core/Project.js:91:10)
[ERROR]     at install (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/install.js:29:20)
[ERROR]     at /apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:33:28
[ERROR] From previous event:
[ERROR]     at withLogger (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:14)
[ERROR]     at Function.runFromArgv [as line] (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:30:16)
[ERROR]     at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/jenkins/jenkinshome/workspace/Guidewire/de.vhv.vhv-hygieia/UI/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:83:26)
```

When I run the build from outside our company, without the proxy, it runs just  fine. When I look into the bower-resolver, it has cached 22 repositories before it broke on th 23nd.

Any thoughts what this could be caused by?

Answer (score 0):

While this article is targeted towards NPM, in my experience it seems to apply to Bower as well:
[Why am I getting 404 for some npm packages?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-am-i-getting-404-for-some-npm-packages/)

**TLDR;** Go to Advanced settings and select "Bypass HEAD Requests" and then zap your cache.